# How do I save and rename an active workbook to a sharepoint site

Tags: vba, excel

This Sub should save an openwork book to a share-point site and name it for the user.

I know Object required is either from misspelling or from referencing an object that doesn't exist. I can't see any spelling mistakes with the below and I think I've declared the four variables being used to build the .SaveAs line.

What am I missing?

---

This is the line that's throwing up the error:

```
.SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
```

Full Save File Code:

```
Sub Save_To_Sharepoint()

Const FileExtStr As String = ".xlsm"
Const FileFormatNum As Long = 52

Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String

TempFilePath = ("\\sharepoint\goes\here") & "\"
TempFileName = Range("A1").Text

'Build .SaveAs file Name based on variables established previously

 With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
 End With

'Display successful submission message
MsgBox ("Thank you, your assessment has been successfully submitted.")

End Sub
```

Comment: `Destwb` is empty , i.e. Nothing

Comment: If you are always running this on the active workbook, don't use `Destwb` - just use `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit`. Go to Tools > Options, check that "require variable declaration" checkbox. Thank yourself later.